# How to Unprotect and Clear the E constant?

Tags: clear

By default, E is used to represent the Euler's number in Mathematica.
I need the variable E to behave just like other undefined variables in my code. When I run the commands

```
Unprotect[E]
Clear[E]
```

the variable E remains black, which means it still holds a value.
Next, If I run

```
1.0E
```

Mathematica gives

```
2.71828
```

How can I completely clear this predefined value?

Comment: Your example's result is governed by numeric evaluation, the `N` function. You can define (after `Unprotecting` `E`), e.g. `N[E] = 0`, and that would change the result in your example. As a result, `E`  will acquire so-called `NValues`: `NValues[E]` will not be empty list. But I'd think twice before doing such hard redefinitions for such a fundamental constant as `E`, it can have all kinds of unobvious consequences for your Mathematica session / calculations.

Comment: There are a number of alternative "E"s that you can redefine.  E.g. \[ScriptCapitalE], \[DoubleStruckCapitalE], \[CapitalEpsilon]

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to encourage beginners to unprotect fundamental constants. Let's make Pi equal to 3 -- it would make geometry much easier!

Comment: @BillS Can we make E into 2 3/4? It takes around two hours and forty five minutes to cut down a modest-sized tree, so this qualifies as a natural logger rhythm.

Comment: This sounds like a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to do with your re-defined `E`?

Comment: Better to get used to using lowercase variables.

Comment: @Roman My program reads the input data for the elastic modulus from a CSV file. Assume that the user enters E as a parameter for the elastic modulus. Mathematica will interpret it as the Euler's number.

Comment: There are far safer ways to do this than to redefine (or undefine) `E`. Check ref/format/CSV in the documentation (Help > Wolfram Documentation, then enter "CSV"). With `"Numeric"->False` (or `Automatic`, I think) you get strings rather than numbers. `StringReplace` can then change occurrences of the character E into something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Unprotect[E]
Remove[E]

E = .5
(*0.5*)

1.0 E
(*0.5*)
```

On the other hand after removing `E`

`Esc`ee`Esc//N`

```
(*2.71828*)
```

This works, but it is a very bad idea.

The easiest way to get `E` back to the proper value is to `Quit`.